# Twilio <connect> with <dial>

Tags: twilio

i have one question for you, can you please tell me if I want to establish the call between my desktop and my mobile number and also send both of the tracks to the wss server and then transcribe them and then make the tts from that transcription using AWS polly and then send the raw audio data to the person who is calling. how can i acheive this?

Note: with connect, it only connect my incoming call to the wss not the actual call between two users. how can i acheive the above?

I have tried to do with  tag but it only makes the connection with wss server not the connection between two users, i want to use the combination of it. how can i do this?